# Trying to graph trajectory function in Mathematica? Won't Graph?

Tags: plotting, physics

The exercise is:

> Define the trajectory function `y(x)` in *Mathematica*. Pick the
>   initial speed (in meters per second) equal to `2` and the angle equal
>   to `30 degrees`. Plot this function from `x=0` to `x=0.5`.

---

I approached this problem by typing

```
y[x_] := x*Tan[θ] - ((9.8*x^2)/(2*v^2*(.5 + (.5*Cos[2 θ]))))
```

I then assigned θ and initial speed:

```
 θ==30

v==2
```

and then wrote the plot function:

```
Plot[y, {x,0,0/5}]
```

AND THEN GOT AN EMPTY GRAPH! HELP!

Comment: `==` is not assignment. Also, use `y[x]` in `Plot` not `y` alone. It seems that you know `/` is division so why you set `.5` as `0/5` in `Plot`?

Comment: Also you need to write `30 Degree` because `Cos[theta]` works with radians. `Degree` will convert your value to radians. Kuba forgot to say what IS assignment, `=` is used for assignment to variables.

Answer (score 4):

```
θ = π/6;  (* changed 30 degres to radians         *)
v = 2;    (* replace == by =. ":=" would do too   *)
y[x_] := x Tan[θ] - ((9.8 x^2)/(2 v^2 (.5 + (.5 Cos[2 θ]))))
                  (* "*"'s are OK but not required        *)
Plot[ y[x], {x, 0, 0.5}]
                  (* replaced y by y[x] and 0/5 by 0.5    *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
y[x_, theta_, v_] := x*Tan[theta] - ((9.8*x^2)/(2*v^2*(.5 + (.5*Cos[2 theta ]))));
values = {theta -> 30 Degree, v -> 2};
Plot[y[x, theta, v] /. values, {x, 0, 0.5}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For explanation on use of `/.` for replacement of values in expression see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html

To make it easy to make changes in parameters, Manipulate can be used

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{x},
  Plot[y[x, theta, v], {x, 0, to}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300, 
        ImagePadding -> 30]
  ],

 Grid[{
   {Control[{{theta, 30 Degree, "theta?"}, 0, 360, 1}], Dynamic[theta]},
   {Control[{{v, 2, "v?"}, 0, 10, .1}], Dynamic[v]},
   {Control[{{to, 1, "to?"}, .1, 10, .1}], Dynamic[to]}
   }
  ],
 Initialization :>
  (
   y[x_, theta_, v_] := x*Tan[theta]-((9.8*x^2)/(2*v^2*(.5 + (.5*Cos[2 theta ]))))
   )
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO, introducing rules like this without explanation is not helpful for someone who is clearly very new to MMA and is struggling with assignments. I would suggest assigning variables like the OP, but correctly with `=`.